# Passing bash parameters to c++

Tags: c++, bash

I tried passing two parameters from bash to c++ program to be used but cant seem to get it to work exactly right. I would use the command `./bash "Turtle" "Cat"` in linux command line.

```
#!/bin/bash
./main.out $1 $2
```

But the C++ file would only read `./main.out` from `argv`. The `cout` would just print cut off versions of `./main.out` such as `./main.out` then `/main.out` and then `main.out`. Am I incorrectly using the parameters in the placement of the bash file?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cout << argv+0 << endl;
    cout << argv+1 << endl;
    cout << argv+2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post your main function code

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This should include example C++ code that you are executing from the bash script as well as how you run the bash script

Comment: Try looking at `argv [1]` rather than `argv [0]`

Comment: Maybe it's because $1 and $2 are empty?

Comment: Sorry, I added what was requested. cout would only print cut off versions of `./main.out` such as `./main.out` then `/main.out` and then `main.out`

Comment: Try to print also "argc" wich is number of parameters to see how many parameters you have

Comment: `char *argv[]` is a pointer of pointers (same as `char **argv`), you need `cout << argv[1] << endl;`

Comment: argc would reproduce the number 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are not printing the arguments as strings, your printing their ***memory locations***. In clang++-9 (what I tested it in) this is what happens when a pointer is passed to std::cout, in many compilers (MSVC, correct me if im wrong) this will simply print nothing.

What you need to do is reference it as an array index and print that

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cout << argv[0] << endl;
    cout << argv[1] << endl;
    cout << argv[2] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works fine for me (passing arguments manually when executing) when compiled with clang++-9. If you are going to use this code you should also check that there are at least 3 arguments (value of `argc`) otherwise you may point at invalid memory when indexing argv

Also try and avoid std::endl and use "\n" instead, std::endl needlessly flushes the buffer and is not required 99% of the time

Answer (score 2):

Your bash file is fine. The problem is in your C++. Try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    std::cout << argv[1] << "\n";
    std::cout << argv[2] << "\n";
}
```

[warning: this doesn't check for errors, so if you don't pass any parameters, it'll misbehave badly.]

Answer (score 1):

`char *argv[]` is a pointer of pointers (same as `char **argv`), you need

```
cout << argv[1] << endl;
```